# HQL Where clause with Case if field is null

Tags: hibernate, case, hql, where-clause, clause

I have a `HQL` query in join between 2 table, with `field1` that may be null or with value.

If it is null in first table I have to check if in the second table 'is null' but if it is with value I have to check if `table1.field1=table1.field1`

How can I do this with 'Case When' in HQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the HQL query should be something like this:

```
SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.t2 = t2 AND
t1.field1 = (CASE WHEN t2.field1 is null THEN NULL ELSE t2.field1 END)
```